# Does this manuscript status change mean it is a desk rejection?

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission, rejection

I submitted my manuscript 2 weeks ago to a Wiley journal that uses ScholarOne to manage submissions.  It went from Submission received to Selecting/assigning Reviewers, then to Evaluating Recommendation.  Given the short amount of time this happened, is this most likely going to be a desk rejection?

Comment: Why don't you relax and wait til  you get something substantial from them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I predict the fate of my manuscript (from information other than a decision letter)?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/153925/7734)

Comment: Such fast evaluation by reviewers is rare but does happen occasionally.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that a *yes* or *no* answer to your question will do is tell you someone else's opinion (not knowledge) based on even ***less*** information (precise dates, journal name, etc.) than you already have!  So instead of trying to second-guess the outcome of the editorial process, just wait.

If you plan on publishing more than one paper in your lifetime, waiting is something you need to get used to.

Editorial processes take time. If your paper impressed the reviewers, seemed like a good fit with the journal overall, or even with the contents of a particular issue, you might get a rapid acceptance. If your paper fits poorly with the journal, you might get a rejection even if the overall quality of your paper is good.