# Editor Assigned Pending to Reviews Completed in Less Than a Day

Tags: mathematics, journals

I submitted to a mathematics journal on August 20, 2023, and the next day the system status changed to 'Editor Assigned Pending'. It remained 'Editor Assigned Pending' until September 18th.  However, yesterday, September 19th, it directly changed to 'Review Completed.' What's going on? Does this mean it's going to be rejected? Because mathematical reviews typically take longer, it feels like a rejection

Comment: On the 18th, it remained 'Editor Assigned Pending,' but on the 19th, it switched to 'Review Completed.' This caught my attention. It had been 'Editor Assigned Pending' for a month and I assumed it hadn't reached the editor yet, so it appears as though the review process only took a day.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Can I predict the fate of my manuscript (from information other than a decision letter)?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/153925/7734)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to answer your question without knowing the inner workings of the journal you submitted to. Electronic submission systems rely on human input and are therefore subject to an even wider variety of errors. It is of course quite possible that the editor that was finally assigned your paper decided on a desk reject, but there are other ways to interpret what has happened.