# Is it a bad sign if a review of a revised manuscript completed within few hours?

Tags: peer-review

Has anyone had a similar experience? My revised manuscript was sent out for a new round of peer review yesterday. This morning, I found one of the reviewers had already finished the review, which is unusual. Is it a bad sign?

Comment: Better to let the process play out rather than fortune telling from every piece of information. Stop checking manuscript status and do something more productive.

Comment: Also see: [Can I predict the fate of my manuscript (from information other than a decision letter)?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/153925/7734)

Comment: If you addressed that reviewers comments adequately it should not take long for them to check. Particularly if it is a minor revision. But, really, you have no authority or influence over the result now, and can only accept what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that it's a revised manuscript, this is not a bad sign. It just means your reviewer had time to check it immediately (or that the requested revisions were minor so they didn't need much time to check it). In fairness, it's not necessarily a bad sign even if it's not a revised manuscript, as well, but revised manuscripts tend to have a faster review time.

Either way there's nothing to do except wait.

Answer (score 2):

As so many other things about peer review, *you just don't know*. There is no way for you to know what the reviewer wrote, and more importantly, *there is nothing you can do about it*. It is not worth worrying about this until you get the paper back from the editor.

Move your brain to more productive things. Write the next paper. Grade those homeworks. Do the review you were invited a few hours ago and get it off your desk within just one day, taking the time to write useful feedback to the authors.