What does this kind of ”Decision Pending“ mean？
I submitted my manuscript to Talyor Francis and it went to “Decision Pending” directly after the “With Journal Administrator” stage. Is it likely to be rejected? author dashboard screenshot
Thanks a lot!

Does this answer your question? https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/153925/can-i-predict-the-fate-of-my-manuscript-from-information-other-than-a-decision

I know that this is hard, but this takes time and there is nothing you can do about it. So just don't look at the progress, and focus on things you can have an impact on like writing your next article, or further improve a course you are teaching, or cook a meal for a loved one, or ....
