'Decision on process' directly from with editor
I have submitted my original research manuscript to a reputed journal in Elsevier, initially it showed with editor and after 5 days it started showing decision in process.Its been 20 days since it showed decision in process.No mail, nothing.any idea?

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/153925/can-i-predict-the-fate-of-my-manuscript-from-information-other-than-a-decision This might be the more appropriate target.
