Protocol of review process of article submission
I am totally new to submitting articles to journals and I have only one (probably naive) question. I submitted a preprint (quite) some time ago and this is the protocol of the process:
Process
Apart from not fully knowing how a review process at a journal works, I recently got the update "decision letter being prepared" after just one day the "associate editor decision started". Does one day mean that the preprint has been rejected? I submitted it to a mathematical physics journal. The preprint contains quite a large amount of equivariant homotopy theory that is applied to the theory of so-called frustrated spin systems.

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like-how-should-i-interpret-a, https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/153925/can-i-predict-the-fate-of-my-manuscript-from-information-other-than-a-decision

These are nice resources!

It just means the editor took one day between pushing buttons. Whether during that time they were stunned by the gravitas of your paper, were in a crisis of faith from all the bad papers they see, or just hoped no one figures out they forgot pushing the first button for two weeks - no one but the editor knows.
